# Passing FLask App's Endpoint URL using a variable

Tags: flask

How can I pass the endpoint url in the @app.route() using a variable ?

i.e
instead of the code being like this :

@app.route(**"/flaskapp",** methods=["GET"] )

I want it to be like this :

**endpoint_url = '/flaskapp'**

@app.route( **endpoint_url**, methods=["GET"] )

Answer (score 1):

To register an endpoint with a rule stored in a variable, you can use [`add_url_rule`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule).

```py
def greet():
    return 'Hello World'

rule = '/hello'
app.add_url_rule(rule, view_func=greet)
```

```py
rule = '/hello'
app.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint='greet')

@app.endpoint('greet')
def greet():
    return 'Hello World'
```